# Connecting LCD, I2C, and RFID tag to ESP32 DevKit

Tags: i2c, esp32, lcd, rfid

I want to connect an LCD, I2C, and an RFID card reader to ESP32 DevKit. My problem is they both have an SDA pin and on the ESP32 I only see one, so how can I work with that?

Comment: Casey Ntsako - Welcome :) Stack Exchange has different rules to typical forums. Since you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help]. There is also a long [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931). Questions should include [the research that you have done](/help/how-to-ask). If you are new to I2C then that's OK (everyone has to start somewhere), but there are many tutorials and reference pages where you can start. Please [edit] your question to add links to proper datasheets for the devices you are using. A signal called SDA might, or might not, be an I2C bus. Show your research. Thanks.

Comment: You can check this thread: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/esp32-rfid-rc522-i2c/1100200

Answer (score 0):

I2C uses addressing for multiple devices on the same bus. Set your LCD (driver) and RFID card reader to two different addresses.